# "You can't forward declare classes that overload operator&"?

Tags: c++, gcc

In the Google C++ Style Guide, there's a section on [Operator Overloading](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Operator_Overloading) that has a curious statement:

> Overloading also has surprising
>   ramifications. For instance, you can't
>   forward declare classes that overload
>   `operator&`.

This seems incorrect, and I haven't been able to find any code that causes GCC to have a problem with it. Does anyone know what that statement is referring to?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

5.3.1 of the Standard has "The address of an object of incomplete type can be taken, but if the complete type of that object is a class type that declares operator&() as a member function, then the behavior is undefined (and no diagnostic is required)."

I didn't know this either, but as another poster has pointed out, it's easy to see how it could cause a compiler to generate incorrect code.

Answer (score 16):

I hadn't heard of it either, but this gives potentially confusing results for the same code before and after the overload:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo;

void bar (Foo& foo) {
    std::cout << &foo << std::endl;
}

class Foo {
public:
    bool operator & () { return true; }
};

void baz (Foo& foo) {
    std::cout << &foo << std::endl;
}

int main () {
    Foo foo;

    bar(foo);
    baz(foo);

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
0x7fff092c55df
1
```

Though there are other reasons why you wouldn't do that anyway - overloading address-of doesn't play nicely with stl or much generic code.

Comment: Now that is interesting and makes sense. Perhaps it isn't "disallowed" by the standard, but instead has unreliable results depending on if the definition of the class/struct is provided yet.

Answer (score 6):

I think the statement isn't precise.  Like the other answers, I'm guessing here.  First, I'm assuming they're referring to [unary operator& and not binary operator&](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/YourAddress.html).  That is:

```
int x = 5;
int* p = &x; // unary &
if (x & 1)   // binary &
```

You can forward declare any class you want.  However, if the class overloads unary operator&, and you call unary operator& on a pointer to one of those objects you'll probably get inconsistent behavior (sometimes you'll simply get the address, and sometimes you'll call the overloaded method).  This could easily turn into something nearly impossible to debug.

---

I'm glad fizzer actually looked at the standard and didn't just guess.

Comment: As pointed out by fizzer, it's undefined behaviour.  Never good.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the ability to overload operator& the boost library offers up the [handy template addressof()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/utility/utility.htm#addressof) to take care of finding the real address of a class. Not that I'm suggesting you overload operator&, but if you need to, help is available.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited to account for comments:**

<s>This is a guess, but one of the main reasons to forward declare is to be able to declare pointers to that class.  The compiler has to make assumptions about the class before having the definition - for example, the size of pointers.</s>

Is it possible to change the size of T* by overloading operator& for a T? (EDIT: Commentors -- and I think not) -- but

What assumption is violated by overloading operator& -- how does it change the class?

Here is one way.

I could write:

```
class A;

void f(A& x) {
    A* xPointer = &x;
}
```

That has a new meaning if operator&() is overloaded than if not, and the compiler may think it can generate code for it, but it would be wrong.

Comment: I believe that pointers are always the same size (which is why the compiler can assume the size..) except for the case of pointers to member functions, which aren't really "pointers" in the traditional sense anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I think so -- I'm just trying to start from the premise that the point of forward declaring a type is so that the compiler can start making some assumptions about it without having the full declaration.  What assumption is violated by having operator&.

Comment: I updated with an example of something that is violated by later defining operator&

Comment: Yes - it's specifically the use of & followed by the overloaded operator& definition that is disallowed.  Looks like the declaration itself is legal provided you never use it, or just use it to declare references.

Answer (score 0):

The wording is unclear, you can of course forward declare the class - but the rule is obviously taking the position that you "shouldn't" where the class overloads `operator&`.

Similar rules are also present in other coding standards, for example [JSF(pdf)](http://www.research.att.com/~bs/JSF-AV-rules.pdf) rule 159 states that `operator&` should not be overloaded.